# Como converter todo ASCII escrito para texto

Tags: vb.net

Consegui converter todo o texto que o usuário escreveu na `TextBox` para ASCII, porém o contrário não. Como posso fazer essa conversão de ASCII para texto?

```
Private Sub BtnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnConvert.Click
    ConvertedTXT.Clear()
    If TxtAscii.Checked = True Then
        While TheLength <> WaitingTXT.Text.Length
            ConvertedTXT.Text += (AscW(WaitingTXT.Text(TheLength)) & " ")
            TheLength += 1
        End While
        TheLength = 0
    ElseIf AsciiTxt.Checked = True Then
        ConvertedTXT.Text += (ChrW(WaitingTXT.Text(TheLength)) & " ")
    End If
End Sub
```

O código apresenta o erro abaixo:

| Código | Descrição | Projeto | Arquivo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BC32006 | Valores "Char" não podem ser convertidos em "Integer". Use "Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW" para interpretar um caractere como um valor Unicode ou "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Val" para interpretá-lo como um dígito. | Ascii Converter | Form1.vb |

Obs: declarei a variável `TheLength` como `Double` inicializada em `0`.

Answer (score 0):

O exemplo disponível no [Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) penso que resolve o seu problema:

```
Dim unicodeString As String = "This string contains the unicode character Pi (" & ChrW(&H3A0) & ")"

' Create two different encodings.
Dim ascii As Encoding = Encoding.ASCII
Dim unicode As Encoding = Encoding.Unicode

' Convert the string into a byte array.
Dim unicodeBytes As Byte() = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString)

' Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
Dim asciiBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes)

' Convert the new byte array into a char array and then into a string.
Dim asciiChars(ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length) - 1) As Char

ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0)

Dim asciiString As New String(asciiChars)

MsgBox(asciiString)
```